# Unable to print multiple values in a single cell of a csv file using PHP

Tags: php, html, csv

I am not able to print multiple values from `$venue`. Venues values can be      single or multiple since it's a checkbox but right now more than one value would not print in CSV file. What can I change?

```
<?php

$Email=$_REQUEST['Email'];
$FirstName=$_REQUEST['FirstName'];
$LastName=$_REQUEST['LastName'];
$Cell_Phone=$_REQUEST['Cell_Phone'];
$Venue=$_REQUEST['Venue']; 

$message = "".
"Email: $Email" . "\n" .
"First Name: $FirstName" . "\n" .
"Last Name: $LastName" . "\n" .
"Cellphone: $Cell_Phone" . "\n" .
"Venue: $Venue" . "\n" .

//I am able to write to the csv file but not when I have multiple values selected for Venue
$fh = fopen("info.csv", "a");

$cr = "\n";
$data = "$FirstName" . ',' . "$LastName" . ',' . "$Email" . ',' . "$Cell_Phone". ',' . "$Venue". $cr;

if($fh){
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fclose($fh);
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

  header('Location:thanks.html');
  exit;

}

?>
```

This is the HTML for Venue section

```
<fieldset>

                              <legend id="VenueLabel" class="desc" for="Venue[]">
                                <span style="color: #cc0000;">*</span> Venue:
                              </legend>
                              <div>
                                <input id="1" name="Venue[]" type="checkbox" value="166729" tabindex="7">
                                <label class="choice" for="1">Venue 1</label>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                <input id="2" name="Venue[]" type="checkbox" value="166730" tabindex="8">
                                <label class="choice" for="2">Venue 2</label>
                              </div>      
                              <div>
                                <input id="3" name="Venue[]" type="checkbox" value="166728" tabindex="9">
                                <label class="choice" for="2">Venue 3</label>
                              </div>
                            </fieldset>
```

Comment: Why not use fputcsv

Comment: Is `$venue` an array?

Comment: In HTML Vennue must be `Venu[]` and in php you can use `implode` function to convert into sting.

Comment: *"Venues values can be single or multiple since it's a checkbox but right now more than one value would not print in CSV file. What can I change?"* - It maybe not what to change but more to post what you didn't include in the question, the HTML for this. If the answer given below didn't solve it, then you'll be left with nothing but guesswork to deal with.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){...}` that doesn't make any sense. Your code probably won't process what's above it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic That's what I'd also like to know and posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082415/unable-to-print-multiple-values-in-a-single-cell-of-a-csv-file-using-php#comment81115427_47082415) earlier asking to see what the HTML looks for this. I guess they'll have to ping someone directly if we've left the question. I can't keep looking at the post waiting for an update. They don't pay me an "minute by minute wage" here ;-) I left them another comment too. If they left, well... I might have also by the time they get back.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You haven't been getting your paychecks from SO? _Awkward_...

Comment: @Don'tPanic I did, but they dated them for 1984.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sorry, I didn't see the comments here yesterday. Venue is an array, I added the HTML for it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use `fputcsv` to create CSV file in PHP, I have updated your code to use it.

```
$Email=$_REQUEST['Email'];
$FirstName=$_REQUEST['FirstName'];
$LastName=$_REQUEST['LastName'];
$Cell_Phone=$_REQUEST['Cell_Phone'];
$Venue=$_REQUEST['Venue']; 
$Venue_str = implode(', ' , $Venue);

$message = "".
"Email: $Email" . "\n" .
"First Name: $FirstName" . "\n" .
"Last Name: $LastName" . "\n" .
"Cellphone: $Cell_Phone" . "\n" .
"Venue: $Venue" . "\n" .


//I am able to write to the csv file but not when I have multiple values selected for Venue
$fh = fopen("info.csv", "a");


$data = [$FirstName , $LastName, $Email, $Cell_Phone, $Venue_str];

 if($fh){
        fputcsv($fh, $data);
        fclose($fh);
    }

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

  header('Location:thanks.html');
  exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: I agree fputcsv is better for putting CSV into a file, but this doesn't really address the main point of the question, does it?

Comment: Updated the Answer to use `implode`  to convert array to string

Comment: That makes sense. I think it's important to note that if OP uses `implode(', ' , $Venue)`, _they **must** also use `fputcsv` to write the values to the file_. If they use that with their current method of manually constructing the CSV string it will break because of the extra commas, but `fputcsv` will quote and construct the CSV properly.

Comment: I don't see why above won't work, but now my cell with Venue returns no value at all.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the error on my end. This was perfect. Thanks so much.